# no muestra las imagenes en el correo

Tags: nodejs, express, ejs

Tengo un server con `express` que no muestra las imágenes cuando se envía al correo este es el código del server:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const config = require('./config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


//middleware
const middlewareAuth = require('./app/middleware/middlewareAuth');+

//coors
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization');
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) return res.status(200).send();
    next();
});



app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

const router = express.Router();
const port = process.env.PORT || config.port; 
app.set('port', port);

app.use(router);


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/templates');
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use('/api/v1', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));




const middleware = express.Router();
middleware.use(middlewareAuth.verificaToken) 



app.use('/api/v1', middleware);



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("El servidor estÃ¡ inicializado en el puerto ",`${port}` );
});
```

En el ejs tengo

```html
<td align="center" class="celda_sin">
  <img src="<%=public%>/api/v1/images/images_email/warner/header.png"width="800" height="165"/>
</td>
```

Y he intentado de todo pero no hay forma que me muestre en el correo las imágenes, alguna ayuda ? de antemano gracias...no se si me esta faltando algo pero he intentado de todo

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo he resuelto colocando la URL completa.

Ejemplo:

```
<td align="center" class="celda_sin">
<img src="https://tusitioweb.com/public/api/v1/images/images_email/warner/header.png"width="800" height="165"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, no debemos cambiarlo pues hacemos pruebas desde distintas plataformas, desasrrollo, test y produccion y en cada una cambia el dominio, gracias igual por tu tiempo